# Jquery ajax is not reaching succes, but don't throw error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, opencart

I have a jQuery ajax request that is not throwing error, but doesn't reach `success` either.

It looks something like this:

```
 function delete() {
      $("input[name='delete[]']:checked").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/deleteIndexes&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          data: {
            delete_approved: true,
            delete: $(this).val()
          },

          success: function(json) {
            if (json['error']) {
              alert(json['error']);
            }
            if (json['success']) {
              alert(json['success']);
            }
          },

          error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

and a function receiving the data:

```
    public function deleteIndexes() {
      $this->language->load('catalog/product');

      $json = array();
      if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/product')) {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
      } elseif (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($this->request->post['delete_approved'])) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $delete = $this->model_catalog_product->deleteIndexes($this->request->post['delete']);

        if ($delete) {
          $json['success'] = $this->language->get('error_empty_delete');
        } else {
          $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_empty_delete');
        }
      }

      $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

Am I missing something? It does not reach `success`, nor does it throw an error. As far as I know, it's one or the other. How is it possible is not reaching either?

I'm using jQuery 1.8.16, and removing the "async: true" doesn't make any change, it just writes to the console the value from the checkbox and then nothing.

Comment: Just wondering, does it execute the success/error callback at all? What happens if you just `console.log()` or `alert()` the `json`/`jqXHR` parameter in the callback functions? (It may be a bit of a weird question, I just like to debug by printing out lots of extra stuff.)

Comment: nope, nothing. it just sits there like it was funnny to screw my life...

Comment: Put a `console.log()` at the start of your success handler.  It could be getting called with data that you aren't expecting and neither of your `if()` statements would trigger.

Comment: the only thing returned from the ajax is a json with either success or error indexes. nothing else is returned, you can check it at the second codeblock.

Comment: Go to the network tab in the Chrome or Firefox debuggers and see EXACTLY what is going out over the wire and coming back.  This should give you a clue where to look next.

Comment: I use tamper data on firefox for that, it's really complete with info of both post and get requests. anyway, I posted the answer below, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, switching `delete_approved` to any value made it work. I don't know why, because I use a lot "approvals" set as `true` and never had a problem, but this time I had to switch the value to `1` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

What Version of jquery are you using?
`Async: false` has been deprecated as of jquery 1.8.

Use chome dev tools or firefox firebug to see if there is any useful responses returning from console? 
I believe if there is no success or error, the call is not firing at all.

Comment: 1.8.16 - I removed the async feature (wich caused me no trouble in other functions) and still nothing, no error, no success...

Answer (score 1):

Try to check what PHP is returing from the script, i guess it is returning nothing. Try to Alert on Json without check , aka:

```
success: function(json) {

  alert(json);

}
```

See if javascript is not returning error on reading the file, that must occur too.